# Draggable : Cancel all but selected class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm working with JQuery UI (v1.10.2) Draggable widget and there is something I'm trying to do but can't get done.

I would like to use the `cancel` option to select all elements but those with a specified class. Something like `cancel: ":not(.grab)"`

Is it possible ?
Thanks

Comment: I created this [jsFiddle shell](http://jsfiddle.net/PHqjC/) with jQueryUI ready to go. Please edit it to create an example of what you are talking about, press the <kbd>Fork</kbd> button at top, and post the new URL in your question so others can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Nevermind, I had fogotten that there is a option dedicated to that matter. I should have go back to read the documentation... The option name is "handle". Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said my previous comment to gibberish, I totally forgot that there was already an option for that matter : `handle`.

So instead of doing
`cancel: ":not(.grab)"`

I just have to do
`handle: ".grab"`

Easy...
Sorry for the unnecessary question.

Comment: It's not unnecessary at all if it can later help someone else. Thanks very much for sharing your solution.